# How to prove b is positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If A * B is positive and I know that A is positive, how do I prove that B is positive? I have to prove it with just basic laws of numbers, e.g. associative property and stuff like that.

Comment: "stuff like that"?

Comment: If, as you say in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625637/how-to-prove-b-is-positive#comment3314605_1625639), you are not allowed to use greater than/less than, how is a positive number defined?

Answer (score 2):

If we know that $ab>0$ and that $a>0$, then we can divide both sides of the inequality by $a$ to find that $b>0$. Thus, $b$ is positive. Remember that dividing both sides of an inequality does not change the inequality as long as what we're dividing by is positive.

Comment: Ok but the problem with that is that it uses rules I am not allowed to use. Im only allowed to use the associative law for addition, existence of an additive identity commutative law for addition associative law for multiplication, existence of a multiplicative identity, existence of multiplicative inverses, commutative law for multiplication, distributive law, trichotomy law, closure under addition and closure under multiplication. you are not allowed to use greater than signs.

Comment: What "rules" are you allowed to use? Do you mean you are only allowed to use [the definition of an ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Definitions)?

Comment: Sorry check my comment I updated it.

Comment: Other than trichotomy law, one of those laws have anything to do with order. You can't prove this theorem with only those laws. However, if you include the rule that the additive inverse of a positive number is negative, then I think it can be proved.

Comment: Actually, I think you also need to include that the product of two positive numbers is positive. Also, I meant "none" instead of "one" above.

Comment: Yeah I think I misunderstood the question and thought I had to use just basic rules. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** $ a(-b)  = -(ab)$

**Proof:**

$$ab + a(-b) = a(b+(-b)) = a0 = 0$$

Now apply the claim by taking $a = A$ to be positive and $b = -B$ to be the magnitude of your negative number.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:  Since $ab > 0$, there is a number $c < 0$ that $ab + c = 0$.  Multiply this equation by $\frac{1}{a}$ on both sides:  $\frac{1}{a}(ab + c) = \frac{1}{a}(0)$.  Using distribution, we get $\frac{1}{a} \cdot ab + \frac{1}{a}\cdot c = 0$.  This simplifies to $b + \frac{1}{a} \cdot c = 0$.  Since $\frac{1}{a} \cdot c$ is negative, that implies that $b > 0$.  Of course, this will only work if you have the theorem or lemma that a positive times a negative is a negative.  This sounds like you are in a course that is developing these kinds of relationship and so proofing this is dependent on what you have already done.

Answer (score -1):

If $b$ were $0$ then $ab$ would be $0$ too, which is not positive.

If $b$ were negative, then $ab$ would be negative (since positive times negative makes negative).

The only remaining possibility is that $b$ is positive.

Comment: This seems to essentially be assuming the property they are being asked to show.

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson: It's assuming the laws for the sign of $ab$ given the signs of $a$ and $b$. What is being asked is the sign of $b$ given the signs of $a$ and $ab$. I'm reading it as a logical exercise in inverting the known relation, not as anything substantial about ordered fields.